# Rewrite command to align text following \hfill in first row

Tags: hfill

the following command

```
\newcommand{\twentyitem}[5]{%
    \\ \parbox[t][][t]{18mm}{\raggedright \small #1}& 
    \parbox[t]{0.83\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {\emph{\scriptsize#3}}\\%
        #4\\%
        \emph{\small#5}
    }\\
}
```

results in the following style

[image]

As can be seen, the bold text (argument `#2`) is followed by `\hfill` and finally, argument `#3` is displayed on the right side of the screen.

What I want is the date to be shown aligned with the first row of the bold text, i.e. one row higher than right now. Of course, this is related to the `\hfill` command. However, I am not sure how to achieve my goal.

One can download the template [here](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex) and the relevant file is `twentysecondcv.cls` where the function can be found in rows 294-301. Note, however, the function is slightly different to the one posted above, but the problem I am facing is identical.

Could anyone help me rewrite this function?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I am aware that a MWE is always the best way to go. However, the template I use involves several documents linked. As I am not sure how to create a MWE in such circumstances I decided to link the files and also explicitly mark the relevant lines of code. If you are willing to teach me how to create a MWE in such a situation I am more than motivated to edit the question and learn!

Comment: Linking to the class is a good starting point. However the question itself should also contain a small, but compilable test, which shows how to use this class. This way, users could directly start to work on a solution without having to create a test file first.

Comment: with no code shown it's only a guess but probably replace `\textbf{#2}%` by `\textbf{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%`

Comment: Have you tried putting the date in a `\smash{\raisebox{up}{date}}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this is exactly what I was looking for! If you write that as an answer I would mark it as solved!

Comment: Is this **inside** a tabular?  You have a line ending with `&`.

Comment: Actually no. I was wondering the same. However, as I am not that skilled in LaTeX programming I thought it might be related to the `\parbox` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with no code shown it's only a guess but probably replace `\textbf{#2}%` by `\textbf{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%`